# Android Studio 3.1: mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Have recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.1, and at the same time I'm trying the Android P preview.

I'm getting the following error on compiling:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

But I cannot see any instance of `26.1.0` anywhere.  All I have in my gradle is:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

I've tried clearing caches, rebuilding app, etc.  But error remains.

Comment: In the External Libraries list in the project tree, `support-media-compat` isn't showing up? Do you have any Gradle plugins beyond `com.android.application`?

Comment: @CommonsWare hmm I see `support-media-compat-26.1.0` in the External Libraries list.  I'm using the `playLicensing` library, and in the gradle for that I see `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Answer (score 45):

You need to override the conflicted libraries by adding the conflicted libraries to your dependencies block

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Thanks :) Really helps a lot. 

Strange that Google don't fix it in the first place. I am curious why. After all, they should just run gradle with dependency tree and find the rogue dependencies.

Answer (score 16):

The above warning is not specific to media-compat dependency. They just added example to explain the issue. The issue get resolved by adding v4 lib for me.

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`

in addition to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

No need include

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to **override** the conflicted libraries by adding the conflicted libraries to your dependencies block. For example, from your error log you'll find the following:

> Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less...

You can remove the error by adding the libraries with something like this:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1`
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1`
}
```

Answer (score 7):

this error came,when i connect app to firebase.

no need to add any thing.

just put mouse cursor on error line(below one) and press Alt+Enter

`(implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0')`

in the list enter first option.(noinspection)

After that it looks like this,

`//noinspection GradleCompatible
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: I'm using firebase-core too and this fixed my warning. Thanks.

Comment: It's a pleasure! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some dependency — perhaps playLicensing — has a transitive dependency on at least `support-media-compat`, for version `26.1.0`.

To work around this:

- Identify each Support Library artifact that shows up in "External Libraries" that is older than `28.0.0-alpha1`. Based on the error, those older ones should all be `26.1.0`, and it will be at least `support-media-compat`.
- For each of those, add your own `implementation` line to your dependencies, requesting that artifact, but for `28.0.0-alpha1`. This will cause Gradle to use the newer artifact, which happens to be what you want.
- Hope that whatever is depending on those older artifacts will survive with the newer artifacts.

So, at minimum, you are adding:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: With that I get the following when doing a gradle sync: "org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preDevproDebugBuild'  ...  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-media-compat' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (28.0.0-alpha1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution"

Comment: @drmrbrewer: Hmmm... you could follow the suggestion, though I haven't used that feature of Gradle and so I don't know the details. You could also try having both a `compileOnly` and an `implementation` dependency on `28.0.0-alpha1`, though I don't know if that will work.

Comment: OK, will try.  Why is this happening now?  Is it Android Studio 3.1?  Or Android P preview?  Or using 28.0.0-alpha1 support libraries?

Comment: @drmrbrewer: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: The key seemed to be to use `api` rather than `implementation` in the playLicensing module (and others)... recently I changed them all to `implementation` from `compile` and it was fine until (I think) when I tried out the P preview and related support libraries.  So it seems that I should stick with `api` in each module?

Comment: @drmrbrewer: If you're writing an app, `implementation` and `api` are supposed to be identical, AFAIK. The difference comes in if you are creating a library (`api` is exposed to consumers of your library, `implementation` is not).

Comment: Hmm, well I'm writing an app, and using `api` in the module's gradle rather than `implementation` did make all errors/warnings go away.  My project structure is as per this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TiqUyabHOxhs2gapJq3XFxyCxj7vA7ss.  There are two modules, each with their own build.gradle: `playLicensing` (google's) and `devmilColor` (third-party color picker, tweaked for my purposes)

Comment: @drmrbrewer: Library modules are libraries.

Comment: OK sorry I wasn't aware of the terminology.  So, with my project structure, it is correct to use `api` in the library modules (x2) and `implementation` in the app?

Comment: @drmrbrewer: Basically, `api` says "this dependency is part of this library/module's API to anything that depends on this library/module". I can't really tell you whether what you're doing is correct, as I don't know much about your app. But particularly if you are not planning on distributing those modules as libraries to others, what you do is really up to you. So, if `api` works, roll with it.

Comment: All a bit confusing.  I have no intention of distributing these modules... I have one app and that's the only place they're used.  When I revert to sdk 27, and support libraries for 27, I can use `implementation` in the library modules and everything syncs and compiles fine.

Answer (score 2):

add in dependencies of build.grad (Module.app)

```
dependencies {
 //noinspection GradleCompatible
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I resolved it by adding this below the error line.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding support-v4 helped me to got loose of warning.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    // other dependencies
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a firebase in your project?
Using firebase core or firebase app indexing seem to be causing the problem.
I was having the same problem, but commenting on firebase packages makes the error to go away

```
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your gradle file has the below dependency. Add this to your app level build.gradle.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
```